# Extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with a $p$-th root of 1

Tags: number-theory

Hensel's lemma gives us a strong tool to look at the degree of cyclotomic extensions over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, but it fails when I try to see what is the degree of the extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ when I add a $p$-th primitive root of unity.

I know that the minimal polynomial of the extension must divide the $p$-th cyclotomic polynomial, but how do I know if it factors or not over $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: What do you call the p-th cyclotomic polynomial ? A primitive pth root of 1 is  a root of $f(X)=X^p -1/X-1$, and the irreducibility of $f(X)$ over $\mathbf Q_p$ is equivalent to that of $f(X+1)$, which is Eisenstein with coefficients in $\mathbf Z_p$.

Comment: Thankyou, this was just what I needed. For $p$-th cyclotomic polynomial I mean exactly $f(X)=X^{p}-1/X-1$.